# IntelliJ IDEA: How to Stop Bash Shell Script Invocation from Opening a New Terminal Session When Using the > Run Button

Tags: bash, shell, intellij-idea, terminal, build

I've created a Run/Debug Configuration that sets my Script path to my Bash shell script (.sh).

I've got Git Bash set as the terminal shell type (I've tried Power Shell, Dos CMD, Cygwin Bash et-al) which my script executes in when invoked.

All this works great.

The only problem I've got is that each time I run the configuration/script, it opens up a new terminal session instance in the IDE.  Over time, I end up with lots of terminal sessions, created after each time I build my code via the script.

Of course I can just close them manually each time, and I could also invoke the script from the command-line from within a single opened terminal session, but I'm specifically trying to create a workflow that allows the use of the > Run button in the IDE toolbar to run my script in a single terminal session tab, then when I press the > Run button again, the script runs again in that same terminal session tab.

Does anybody know a way of doing that, if it's even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the Run/Debug Configuration to run the script in the terminal, I can untick that option and specify the shell in the 'Interpreter path' of the Run/Debug Configuration.

When the > Run button is pressed, the script is invoked in the 'Run' tab instead of the 'Terminal' session tab.

[image: Run/Debug Configuration set interpreter path to bash.exe]

Comment: Mine is a script text instead of script file. And when I did what you said it throws this error:

Error running 'Build': Cannot run program "\bin\sh" (in directory "my-project-path"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

In Run/Debug Configurations (doubleclick the script to open the dialog) uncheck "Allow multiple instances".

This was bugging me for a year. I hope this helps in your case as well.